# Return a specific value 'Open' where days are between Monday - Friday and time is >=8:00 & <19:00 all other days and times should return 'OOH'

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, lambda, google-sheets-formula, nested-if

Return a specific value 'Open' where days are between Monday - Friday and time is >=8:00 & <19:00 all other days and times should return 'OOH'

Open = >=8:00 & <19:00 & Monday to Friday inclusive
OOH = >=19:01 & <7:59 & Monday to Friday & anytime on Saturday or Sunday

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tVhwBPBtT7a3RhjhVIi9UAqeCAIgBLYJKj5PchNdlyA/edit?usp=sharing

I currently tried these formulas independently but I would like one formula to do the job:

```
=INDEX(counta(IF((HOUR(A2:A)>=8)*(HOUR(A2:A)<19), "OPEN", "OOH")))
```

The above returns all data that I require considering the time only this is shown in Sheet1!B2:B

```
=query(countif(filter(text(Sheet1!A:A,"dddd"),len(Sheet1!A:A)),"Sunday"))
```

The above returns the number of Sundays which could then be removed from the data along with Saturdays however the data would be skewed if I did this as the times are considering all days at present.

Sheet1!C2:C should show either Open or OOH for each date/time

Comment: Kindly add input table and expected output table as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Comment: Updated question, formulas and test sheet to make more sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(LAMBDA(x, IF(NOT(REGEXMATCH(TEXT(x, "ddd"), "Sat|Sun"))*
 (TIMEVALUE(x)>=("8:00"*1))*(TIMEVALUE(x)<("19:00"*1)), "Open", "OOH"))(A2:A))
```

[image]